# React Native network debugging does not work with GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo-client, chrome-debugging

I am using [React Native Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) for debugging my React Native application. But when I am trying to inspect GraphQL queries (sent by Apollo Client) I have `Nothing to preview` in debugger's `Preview` window. No errors, no communicates why it happens. It seems debugger cannot parse response somehow? Response from server is sent correctly. Is it known issue?

[image]